# Facebook 3.x SDK Notification not firing?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I was wondering if anyone knew why the FBSessionDidSetActiveSessionNotification, FBSessionDidUnsetActiveSessionNotification, FBSessionDidBecomeOpenActiveSessionNotification or FBSessionDidBecomeClosedActiveSessionNotification never gets fired when I open a new FBSession session?

The only way I got to detect the FBSessionDidBecomeOpenActiveSessionNotification & FBSessionDidSetActiveSessionNotification is when I call [FBSession setActiveSession:]; explicitly.

Basically, I got something like that:

```
_session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID: FACEBOOK_AppId
                                permissions: _facebookPermissions
                            defaultAudience: FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                            urlSchemeSuffix: nil
                         tokenCacheStrategy: nil];

    [_session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                          FBSessionState status,
                                          NSError *error) {

        [FBSession setActiveSession: _session];
        // ...
    }];
```

Is that normal that I have to call [FBSession setActiveSession:]; ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions
                        allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                   completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
```

Comment: Yeah that works too... But it's deprecated. So I probably shouldn't use it now.

Comment: I don't think it is.. See here https://developers.facebook.com/ios/change-log-3.x/

Comment: Well look in FBSession.h for Facebook SDK 3.1. Here's the declaration of that method; It's deprecated by Facebook (see __attribute__((deprecated)));

Comment: in 3.1 you have to request read permission and write permissions separately. Use openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions for login. Later when you need to publish/write, use reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:completionHandler. See this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/

Comment: That's what I figure out a few days ago. I don't think it's safe to use openActiveSessionWithPermissions with the way Facebook wants use to do things now in 3.1 Plus, the method is mark deprecated.

Comment: Facebook suggest using openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler: or openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI see documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions
                            allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                       completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
```

That is really just a helper function for doing something similar to what you're already doing, though.  If you grab the source from the git repo, you can see what's going on in FBSession.m.